# Railstutorial.org: Authentication only works in the same device as created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the railstutorial.org in creating my own authentication system but it looks like there's an error.

The sign_in only works when the user has been created in the same device.

**e.g:**

1) I deploy the app to heroku

2) I create the user on my MAC

3) I try to sign in on my iPhone

4) Failure.

**Link** : http://railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top

The same happens if you replace "my MAC" for iPhone of for any other computer.

Could it be because of sessions?

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't solve the problem directly but why not try a prebuilt authentication system like [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). People have put a lot of effort into solving many of the issues that you might come across and it seems crazy to re-create the wheel in terms of login.

Comment: Thanks. Is it easy to replace all I have with devise? I already have everything setup. Models, controllers, etc.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard. Devise follows a very similar pattern with a user model and session controllers etc it just does most of the work for you. You really don't want to risk security exploits from tiny bugs either.